# How to optimise result of a macro with Excel solver?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, solver

This is my first title here. I hope I do not make any formatting mistakes.

I have been having issue to trigger a macro and optimise its result with excel solver.
I have not seen such an example and not sure if I can do it with excel solver in vba.

In other words, I have a macro code and it takes 1 min to find a solution. My input paramaters and constraints are in an excel spreadsheet. However to get the solution I need to run the macro code and optimise its result with excel solver by changing my variables but I could not find how to do it.

1-) I first tried to trigger the macro (BothMethod) when the solver changes the variables; however, this approach did not work properly.

2-) I later tried to use '''SolverOptions, StepThru:=True''' together with '''SolverSolve, ShowRef:="MyMacro"''' but was not able to run the macro and optimise its result.
One of my vba code is as below;

Macro code BothMethod writes its result to "$AO$120" and I want to minimise it by changing cells "$AI$120:$AI$131". But I am not able to run the macro while the solver is working, hence "$AO$120" does not change with the change of variables.

I hope someone can help me to sort this out.
Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SolverTest1()

    Worksheets("Inputs").Activate

    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AO$120", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        "$AI$120:$AI$131", Engine:=3
        
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AI$120", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$AJ$120"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AI$121", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$AJ$121"
    
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AI$120", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$AG$120"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$AI$121", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$AG$121"   
       
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000001, Convergence:= _
        0.0001, StepThru:=True, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
        
    SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=3, MutationRate:=0.1, Multistart _
        :=True, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
        IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
           
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True, ShowRef:="CallMacro"
    

End Sub

    Function CallMacro()
        Call BothMethod
    End Function
```

Comment: So, if the changing cells are set in the Solver, how long does it take to find a solution without your vba stuff? Are you running an LP model or do you need the other Solver engines due to the functions used in the sheet?

Comment: Hi @Solar Mike. Thanks for reply. Solver does not find a result without my vba code(BothMethod) as the objective cell does not change with the change of variable cells. Then solver just find some arbitrary values for the variable cells. The problem is not linear. Either GRG nonlinear solver or Evolutionary should be used.

Comment: So if the changing cells change then why doesn’t the objective cell change?

Comment: beacuse changing cells are for input for vba code (BothMethod) and objective cell is the result from the vba code (BothMethod) as I am not able to trigger BothMethod while using the excel solver, objective cell does not change with the change of input cells(variables). this is my question. how to trigger the macro (BothMethod) while using the excel solver and optimise its result by changing the input cells?

Comment: The changing cells have to be in the calculation path so that the objective is updated as the cells change. Otherwise it is like expecting the sales price of a BMW to change based on the production costs of a Lada.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: they are in calculation path but  the calculation is not in spreadsheet cells, it is in the macro code. macro need to be run to solve the problem. this is the question I am asking. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: If you make `BothMethod` a user-defined function (UDF) and ensure all input cells/ranges are present in the function's parameter list (so that Excel's calculation engine knows to recalculate it) then it should work.